# Create fresh database from Reverse-engineered EF Core DbContext

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I'm developing an Asp.Net Core Web API which will be interacting with an existing database, I'm using EF Core 3 with a reverse-engineered DbContext.

As part of the development process I would like to configure integration tests using docker, which means testing against a copy of this database in a container.

I am wondering if there's a way to create a new database in the container using the schema defined by the reverse-engineered DbContext rather than keeping (an ultimately maintaining) a copy of a create script, The database would be created at the start of the integration tests and eventually destroyed when the container is dropped

Comment: You need to create migrations of you database context either way. Then you can call dbContext.Database.Migrate() on startup or generate migrations script via dotnet ef command line utility.

Comment: Use EnsureCreated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `EnsureCreated` solution that @ErikEJ suggested in a comment did the trick.

Now in my `OneTimeSetup` method in my Nunit test class, the database is created in the docker image:

```cs
[TestFixture]
class TestClass
{
    [OneTimeSetup]
    public async Task Setup()
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql("connectionString");

        await using var dbContext = new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);

        await dbContext.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync()
    }

    //...Tests
}
```